# In Half-Life 2, how many people would fit in an Combine APC?

Tags: video-games, half-life

In Half-Life 2 (original game or episodes), how many people would fit in an Combine APC?

(Or, in other words, if the lore doesn't say anything, how many CP's or soldiers had been near an APC at most when there's no other way they could get there? If ACP is inactive (parked), this would be total, on other hand, if ACP shoots, then someone else most likely is inside.)